# How to do multi-line equations grouped beside one brace

Tags: functions

[image: Equation]

I am not an engineer nor a mathematician.  I am stuck as i need to write this equation in a linear method so that i can put it into a VBA program i am working on.

I do not understand the order of operations or what it means to have multiple lines beside a bracket.

I need this broken down into steps such as SF(x) = (R1 + (R1-w(x-a)) - r2) etc

But i do not know what the multiple lines mean in order to flatten it out and complete the equation.

An explanation of how to do these multi lined equations would be wonderful aswell as using this example and breaking it into one long line for me.

Thanks in advance!

-Allan

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_function

Comment: Also i'm unsure if the column on the right is a cheat sheet based off the other stuff its with or apart of it

Answer (score 0):

The parts on the right are conditions. For example, if you're in the function SF, you might have this condition for the first part (my VBA is a bit rusty...):

```
If 0 <= x And x <= a Then
  SF = R1
End If
```

And the rest would be similar.

There isn't really a way to stick it all into one line without making it incredibly ugly.

Comment: Perfect!

I don't need it on one line now that i understand how it works.

Thanks